# How can I make an movieclip move in a circular path with GTween?

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I make an movieclip move in a circular path with GTween? it's straightforward to have something move with various easing effects in a line or a curve, but I would need a complete circular path.

Answer (score 2):

Most animation libraries aren't made to support that sort of thing. I wrote a small library for exactly this problem; it's built upon a foundation of spatial path-based animation, rather than generic property interpolation.

You can check it out here: http://blog.generalrelativity.org/actionscript-30/grape-animation-library/

If you're required to use GTween, and it supports curves (probably bezier), you can approximate a circle with multiple curves: http://www.tinaja.com/glib/ellipse4.pdf